# Query SQL with variable parameter in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL query that allows me to do some calculation.
How do I run that specific query for every ItemCode in the ICT_AOI table without having to fill each in one by hand?

For example, instead of only being calculated for 1 itemcode, it would be calculated for all the rows of the table

In the end, for exemple, i want :

B0016 | 0.777,

B0017 | 0.645,

B412 | 0.8545,

B568 | 0.1412,

ect...

Here is my code :

```
SELECT 
    (COUNT(ProgCode)/pICT) AS ICT, ItemCode  
FROM 
    FailOnly, ICT_AOI 
WHERE 
    Machine = 'Seica' 
    AND ProgCode = '3' 
    AND ItemCode = 'B001608AArev9' 
    AND Side = 'A' 
GROUP BY 
    pICT, ItemCode
```

That code return the right result but for one specific row because of my WHERE specification. 
Machine, ProgCode are in a table. Side, ItemCode, pICT are in another table. The two of them can be link by : table1.ItemCode = table2.BoardName.

Comment: You should use parameters in order to use the same query to retrieve different rows.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: i'll change it then.

Comment: What will you use to actually run the query?

Comment: At the end, i need two informations : ItemCode and (count(ProgCode)/pICT).

Comment: I've edited my post to match the real information. Now all is clear. I've done the query for 1 row, but then i use precise data. I would like the query to be general enough to calculate for all rows

Comment: I want to replace : "WHERE 
    Machine = 'Seica' 
    AND ProgCode = '3' 
    AND ItemCode = 'B001608AArev9' 
    AND Side = 'A' ", by something that allows to do the query for each ItemCode ?

Comment: How do I run that specific query for every ItemCode in the table without having to fill each in one by hand?

Comment: Just dont include `ItemCode` in the where clause. It's that simple!

Comment: But then, the count(ProgCode) will count every progCode of the table ? Anyway it's not working, i still have : B001608AArev9 | 0,000702247191011236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are saying, then you can accomplish this using an `OUTER APPLY`

Essentially, this will select all of the distinct ItemCodes from the ITC_AO1 Table, and apply the query to it. Just check the join is on the right condition and the where clause as I couldn't work out if you were specifying the machine, progcode and side each time as well or if that was a genuine filter.

If this doesn't help you then I need to see an example of info in each table and an example result showing what you want included and not i.e duplicates etc.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT ItemCode 
    FROM
    ITC_AOI
    ) as a

    OUTER APPLY 

    (
    SELECT 
    (COUNT(ProgCode)/pICT) AS ICT, ItemCode  
    FROM FailOnly as b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ICT_AOI as c
    ON b.BoardName = c.ItemCode
    WHERE Machine = 'Seica' 
    AND ProgCode = '3' 
    AND a.ItemCode = c.ItemCode 
    AND Side = 'A' 
    GROUP BY pICT, ItemCode
    ) as b
```

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted ! Thank you really much ! Didn't though about the outer apply.

Comment: No problem Alexis! It's a very useful tool, along with the `CROSS APPLY` which is the same but won't return null values when there is no match in the 'Applied' query. Worth having a read about!

Comment: I knew about the Cross join, outer join. What's the difference between  join and apply ? besides the null ?

Comment: Cross Join will return every result possible. So each row of Table A with Each row of table B. It's also known as a Cartesian Product. You don't specify an ON clause for it. The main difference is that with an Apply, you use the where clause to specify the join instead of an on clause and can reference fields from the first query. It's especially useful to join to a Table valued UDF.  If you use a join in this query, anything you filter, will apply to the joined table. With the outer apply you can use an unfiltered list of distinct ItemCodes and join to a query that is filtered as needed

Comment: Okay i see. So it's mostly a difference of visibility, filtering and so results. What mean UDF ?

Comment: A UDF is a User Defined Function. It can accept a variable/variables and return a single value or a table of values based on the variables provided. So you can have a table of IDs, which you pass to a function using an outer apply and then return a result set for each ID. It's similar to what we did here, but the query is essentially contained within a function, so can be called using the function name.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

Here is my code :

```
SELECT ItemCode, (SELECT COUNT(ProgCode)/pICT FROM FailOnly ct WHERE ct.BoardName = tc.ItemCode) as namecounter FROM ICT_AOI tc
```

The sub query allow me to bypass the group by and so have for each row my calculation.